# Access IIf statement retrieving a value using a Check Box

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, iif

I am attempting to have a single List Box pull up two possible values based on whether or not a Check Box is filled.  The Row Source I have for the List Box is:

IIf([Forms]![frmPDPRate]![chkTrue], [qryPDPRate]![Initial], [qryPDPRate]![Renewal])

The specifics are that I'm trying to pull a rate, either Initial or Renewal, based on if [chkTrue] is true or false.

Another note:  The query that the list box should be pulling from has been paired down to one row based on cascading combo boxes. So there is only one possible choice per column in the query.

EDIT:
I think I'm going about this all wrong but I don't know how to get it to do what I want at this point.

Yawar, nothing is happening when I run the form but that makes sense as I can't force the rowsource to choose between two possibilities.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: You are using a field not a query in the `RowSource` property?! That does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @EMett You are correct, I was hoping it would be possible to use an iif statement to guide it to the correct field in a query based on the checkbox but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following code in VBA:

```
Private Sub chkTrue_AfterUpdate()
   If chkTrue =TRUE then
      listbox.RowSource = "SELECT Initial FROM qryPDRRate"
   Else
      listbox.RowSource = "SELECT Renewal FROM qryPDRRate"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the right direction. I guess I made a mistake in my first attempts to use the Query Builder for the listbox, but it can be done through there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the Query Builder in the RowSource Property using an IIf statement. The RowSource Data Looks as such.

SELECT IIf([Forms]![frmPDPRate]![chkTrue],[qryPDPRate]![Initial],[qryPDPRate]![Renewal]) AS Rate FROM qryPDPRate;